# The gradient on sphere in the spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

According to my former question "[The gradient on sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363873/the-gradient-on-sphere)", the gradient of a function $f$ in spherical coordinates is given by
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\mathbb{R}^3} f &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \nabla_{\mathbb{S}^2(r)} f,
\end{align*}
and the gradient on the $r$-sphere is
$$ \nabla_{\mathbb{S}^2(r)} f = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin \varphi} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}. $$

However, according to the post "[What is the metric tensor on the n-sphere (hypersphere)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402102/what-is-the-metric-tensor-on-the-n-sphere-hypersphere)", the metric of $\mathbb{S}^2(r)$ is given by
$$ g_{\mathbb{S}^2(r)} = r^2 d\varphi \otimes d\varphi + r^2 \sin^2 \varphi \, d\theta \otimes d\theta. $$
Using this, we can calculate as follows:
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\mathbb{S}^2(r)} f
&= g^{11}_{\mathbb{S}^2(r)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} + g^{22}_{\mathbb{S}^2(r)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \\
&= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \varphi} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}.
\end{align*}
I'm confused with the difference between the power of $\sin \varphi$. What went wrong?

Here is one more question. Can I write $\nabla_{\mathbb{S}^2(r)}f = \frac{1}{r} \nabla_{\mathbb{S}^2(1)} f$ if $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x) = f(x/ \vert x \vert)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that you've mistranscribed the result from the first link. There the results are written in terms of *unit* basis vectors for the tangent plane of the sphere, not $\partial/\partial\phi$ and $\partial/\partial\theta$.